# How to load and display an image in the image editor using python?

Tags: python, scripting, import, image, uv-image-editor

How could I load an external image and display it in *Image Editor* automatically?  Basically the same as when rendering an image and displaying the *Render Result*.

I'm already able to load the image programatically. However, I don't get how to display the image in the *Image Editor*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the image editor is used in one of the visible areas of the current workspace, you can iterate through [`bpy.context.screen.areas`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Area.html#bpy.types.Area.type) to find the one with type `IMAGE_EDITOR`. The image that is shown in the editor can be set through the [space](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.SpaceImageEditor.html#bpy.types.SpaceImageEditor.image) of the area.

An image can be loaded through [`bpy.data.images.load()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.BlendDataImages.html#bpy.types.BlendDataImages.load).

```
import bpy


img = bpy.data.images["Render Result"]
# img = bpy.data.images.load(filepath)

for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'IMAGE_EDITOR':
        area.spaces.active.image = img
```